# Do you know which WebSphere Portal JAR file contains the class com.ibm.portal.portlet.service.PortletServiceHome?

Tags: websphere, websphere-portal

What is the WebSphere Portal JAR file containing the class:

```
com.ibm.portal.portlet.service.PortletServiceHome
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find out by using the tool that I refer to in this post:
[Find Java classes or packages contained in JAR files](https://codyburleson.com/find-java-classes-or-packages-contained-in-jar-files/)

Answer (score 0):

These files are located in the directory PortalServer_root/doc/compile. 
public_api.jar + public_spi.jar

more info here https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSYJ99_8.0.0/dev/wpsbscfg.html#wpsbscfg__compile

Answer (score 0):

I found it in:
`< portlet base >/base/wp.pe.api.standard/shared/app/wp.pe.api.standard.jar`